# why does the same event recognise different activeElements?

Tags: javascript, html, simultaneous

If I click a button the `activeElement` is the button.
If I leave an input box the `activeElement` is the Window.
If I leave an input box by clicking on a button the `activeElement` is ... both? 
Why does the `onfocusout` event not register the same `activeElement` as the button?
Is there anyway I can access the click-on-button event from the function call of the inputbox-leave-event? 
ie can I ask, "Did you leave me for the lousy button?"

```
<button  type="button" onclick = "myFunction()">   button   </button><br>
<input   type="text" onfocusout= "myFunction()">  </input>

<script>
function myFunction() { 
  console.log(document.activeElement);
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `relatedTarget` in the event will show you where it's leaving to

of course, you have to use `addEventListener` to access the `event` in the first place

But I think this demonstrates what you want to see

it'll definitely tell you

> "Did you leave me for the lousy button?"

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const input = document.querySelector('input')

function buttonHandler(e) {
  console.log('button clicked');
}

function inputHandler(e) {
  console.log('leaving input for', e.relatedTarget?.tagName || 'window');
}
input.addEventListener('focusout', inputHandler);
button.addEventListener('click', buttonHandler);
```

```html
<button type="button">   button   </button><br>
<input type="text"> </input>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bravo! experimenting with your solution I see e.relatedTarget successfully monitors where the activeElement goes next. Perfect! But why doesn't it work for the opposite? Why isn't e.relatedTarget for the button-click-event = to the input-leave-event? Why is it null?

Comment: if my function call from the button relies on the function call results finishing from the input leave event, can that present problems?

Comment: @AndreiCleland - I don't really follow - perhaps some sample code would help

Answer (score 1):

The `activeElement` read-only property of the Document interface returns the Element within the DOM that currently has focus.

Often activeElement will return a HTMLInputElement or HTMLTextAreaElement object if it has the text selection at the time. If so, you can get more detail by using the object's `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

In addition, it is indeed possible to trigger a button click when leaving the input element, you just need to make sure to handle the onfocusout function, and use the code inside the function to trigger the click event, you can refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

```js
function onMouseUp(e) {
  const activeTextarea = document.activeElement;
  const selection = activeTextarea.value.substring(
    activeTextarea.selectionStart, activeTextarea.selectionEnd
  );
  const outputElement = document.getElementById('output-element');
  const outputText = document.getElementById('output-text');
  console.log({ id: activeTextarea.id, selection});
}

const textarea1 = document.getElementById('textarea1');
const textarea2 = document.getElementById('textarea2');
textarea1.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
textarea2.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

```html
<textarea name="textarea1" id="textarea1" rows="7" cols="40">This is Text Area One.</textarea>
<textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" rows="7" cols="40">This is Text Area Two</textarea>
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully, the question is why does the same event recognise different activeElements?
And if you look at my answer carefully, I have already answered this point and derives and supplements other usages. The example is to demonstrate how to use supplementary grammar.

Comment: In addition, in the answer, I also explained the name of the event when leaving the input and how to trigger the grammatical link of the button click

Comment: So what you comment is really inexplicable in my opinion. Have you really read the question and my answer carefully?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener for the button inside the myFunction()

```js
function myFunction() { 
  // console.log(document.activeElement);
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(event);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="btn" type="button">button</button><br>
        <input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that will add an extra event handler every time the input loses focus ... not a good solution